# apache hadoop versions 2.0 vs. 0.23

Tags: hadoop

There are so many Hadoop versions and different distributions which make me confused. I have a few questions.

1. Apache Hadoop 1.x is from 0.20.205?
2. Apache Hadoop 2.0 is from 0.22 or 0.23?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this [blogpost](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/an-update-on-apache-hadoop-1-0/) from Cloudera:

> There is next to no functional difference between 0.20.205 and 1.0. 
>   This is just a renumbering.

Hadoop's [Yarn](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.23.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) site states:

> MapReduce has undergone a complete overhaul in hadoop-0.23 and we now
>   have, what we call, MapReduce 2.0 (MRv2) or YARN

It's also worth to have a look at [this](https://blogs.apache.org/bigtop/entry/all_you_wanted_to_know) diagram too. It shows the tree of different Hadoop versions as well as the 3rd party distributions on top of them.

Comment: updated post can be found [here](http://drcos.boudnik.org/2014/03/hadoop-genealogy-continued-4.html)

Answer (score 3):

updated answer 
http://elephantscale.com/hadoop2_handbook/Hadoop_Versions.html

(disclaimer : I am a co-author of this online book)

Comment: The link is broken. Also, a manual search for that page or any version/release information turned up nothing.

Comment: The link is still broken.

Comment: The link is broken even now!

Answer (score 1):

hadoop release 1.0.0 is avalable from 0.20.x

As a rule of thumb,remember

1.xx is = 0.20.0
2.xx is > 0.20.0

We can easily remember and choose the correct apache distribution for hadoop cluster setup.

Comment: it would be good if you mention about identifying other version numbers for Hadoop 2 also.