# What are the differences between hadoop versions?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

What is the difference between hadoop version 0.x, 1.x and 2.x Also can someone tell me how cdh 3 and 4 differ.

Comment: This is way too broad of a topic to be answered here.  A quick google search returned a couple interesting links... http://www.slideshare.net/KonstantinVShvachko/hadoop-22, http://hortonworks.com/blog/understanding-hadoop-2-0/

Comment: Check the release notes.

Comment: @DJR you may also have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12226763/1050422

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera provides an extensive list of new features and changes in each release:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Release-Notes/CDH4-Release-Notes.html
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Release-Notes/cdh4rn_topic_2.html

You can also look at the list of individual changes from the Vanilla Apache Hadoop releases:

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.CHANGES.txt